# MEAN app: Multer not working. Unable to receive image from front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

So I've been trying to upload an image for a while now, but it doesn't seem to work. I send an image to my service after selecting it in my template. In the service I send it to my node.js server. In this node.js server I use Multer to handle the image file, but it throws an error.

Can someone see why? I'm really new to uploading images so I don't have clue where to begin. Also, my error is not specific, so I can't narrow it down. (*user.service.ts?edaa:20 Backend returned code 500, body was: [object Object]*)

The file I am trying to upload is a .png file

**node.js back-end: I try to use Multer to handle the file upload, but it returns an error.**

```
var multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: '../public/uploads/',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldName + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).single('myImage');


router.post('/uploadProfilePicture/:userId', function(req, res){
    upload(req, res, function (err){
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            msg: "whatever"
        })
    } else {
        console.log(req.file);
        res.status(200).json({
            msg: "sup brah"
        })
    }
});
});
```

**User.service file: Is it possible that I need to add some headers**

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, userId) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        console.log(fileToUpload);
        formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3200/user/uploadProfilePicture/" + userId, formData)
            .map(() => { return true; })
            .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
    }
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
fileToUpload: File = null;

handleFileInput(files: FileList){
        this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
        this.uploadFileToActivity();
    }

    uploadFileToActivity() {
        this.userService.postFile(this.fileToUpload, localStorage.getItem('userId')).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 profilePicSection">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Choose File</label>
            <input type="file"
                   id="file"
                   (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Screenshot of the page and console**

[image: Screenshot of the page and console]

Comment: multer is trying to get the image from field `myImage` but in the frontend you are setting the field `fileKey`. Those two things have to match

Comment: THat's the issue indeed, thanks!